# Get a fresh id in a deterministic manner

Tags: c#, deterministic

I have an `IImmutableDictionary<int, MyType>` in C#. During my program's execution, I would like to add and remove `MyType` instances based on some commands:

```
public sealed class AddMyTypeCommand : ICommand
{
    public readonly MyType myTypeToAdd;

    // etc... 
}

public sealed class RemoveMyTypeCommand : ICommand
{
    public readonly int keyToRemove;

    // etc... 
}
```

When a `MyType` is added, I would like to generate a fresh `int` key that is not already in the the dictionary.

I assume that I will never run out of `int`s because keys may be removed and reused later.

The main catch is that I would like the process to be *deterministic*. For a given stream of `ICommand`s, the code must execute the same (and generate the same keys!) on different machines.

What is a robust, maintainable and efficient approach for achieving the key generation step?

---

For example, a slow approach would be: starting from `int.MinValue`, walk upwards until a fresh id is found.

Comment: Use `GetHashCode()`?

Comment: Are there any requirements for these ids (ie, is 1,2,3,4,5, etc) a valid way to generate ids?

Comment: HashCode or Checksums are a first approach, but there is a small probability that 2 different commands have the same key.

Comment: @Kolichikov Any integer will do. They could be sequential, but they not have to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that you won't be removing a lot more than adding, you can try storing all holes in a Queue, and determining the key based on whether the queue is empty or not. So your Dictionary will auto increment the key if there are no holes, and back fill if there are holes.

```
class ImmutableDictionary<T>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, T> _dict = new Dictionary<int, T>();
    private readonly Queue<int> _holes = new Queue<int>();
    private int _nextInt = 0; //what is next integer to assign, I'm starting at 0, but can be int.MinValue
    private int AssignKey()
    {
        //if we have a hole, use that as the next key. Otherwise use the largest value we haven't assigned yet, and then increment that value by 1
        return _holes.Count != 0 ? _holes.Dequeue() : _nextInt++;
    }

    public void Add(T input)
    {
        _dict.Add(AssignKey(), input);
    }

    public void Remove(int key)
    {
        if (_dict.Remove(key)) //if a remove is successful, we should add a hole
        //you can extend the logic here to not add a hole if you are removing something equal to _nextInt - 1.
            _holes.Enqueue(key);
    }
}
```